# SQL. Defining a parameter by a column from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Tab 1**:

| id | address |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Sumskoy street |
| 02 | Sumskoy passage |
| 03 | Long street |
| 04 | 1st ave |

**Tab 2**:

| name |
| --- |
| Sumskoy |
| 1st |

I need to create a query that will return the same table with the addition of a new column with a condition met:

- if "Tab1.address" matches the "Tab2.name",
- then value is set to `1`
- otherwise value is set to `0`.

**Expected output**:

| address | new_column |
| --- | --- |
| Sumskoy street | 1 |
| Sumskoy passage | 1 |
| Long street | 0 |
| 1st ave | 1 |

**Attempted query**:

```
SELECT
    tab1.adress, 
    CASE WHEN tab1.adress LIKE ('%' || tab2."name" || '%') then '1' else '0' end as New_column
FROM
    tab1,
    tab2
```

**Current (wrong) output**:

| address | New_column |
| --- | --- |
| Sumskoy street | 1 |
| Sumskoy passage | 1 |
| Long street | 0 |
| 1st ave | 0 |
| Sumskoy street | 0 |
| Sumskoy passage | 0 |
| Long street | 0 |
| 1st ave | 1 |

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `MAX` to your `CASE` and `GROUP BY tab1.adress`

```
SELECT
tab1.adress, 
MAX(CASE WHEN tab1.adress LIKE ('%' || tab2."name" || '%') then '1' else '0' end) as New_column
FROM
tab1,
tab2
GROUP BY tab1.adress
```